# expect_call, how to invoke callback function with argument rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, googletest

class A is under test, I want EXPECT_CALL to to return immediately, and invoke lamda function with value 200(rvalue reference) for mocked *asyncfunc()* method. Please read the comments in line with the code

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"  
#include "gmock/gmock.h"  

#include<iostream>  
using namespace std; 

// Concrete class  
class B  
{   
    public:  
       // asyncfunc signature, p2 is function pointer with argument as rvalue referrence  
        bool asyncfunc(int p1, std::function<void(int &&v)> &&p2, float p3){  
            cout << "asyncfunc() \n" << "param1 : " << p1 << "\nparam 3 : " << p3 << endl;  
            p2(100);  
        }   
  
};  

class MockB  
{
    public:  
        // asyncfunc mocked  
        MOCK_METHOD3(asyncfunc, bool (int, std::function<void(int &&v)> &&, float));  
};  
  
// unit under test - A  
template< typename T>  
class A  
{
    T *bobj;  
    void sync(){}  
    public:  
    A(T *pbobj):bobj(pbobj){}    
    void test_function()  
    {
        bool value = bobj->asyncfunc(10, [this](int &&a){  
                    cout << "Lamba : " << a << endl;  
                    if(a == 100)  
                    {  
                      sync();  
                    }  
                },  
                20);  
        cout << "test_function : " << value << endl;  
    }  
};
```

// My tests look like below, I get compilation error

```
TEST(A, test_function)  
{  
    MockB b;
    A<MockB> obj(&b);
    using namespace ::testing;   

    EXPECT_CALL(b, asyncfunc(_,_,_)).WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeArgument<1>(100),Return(true)));  
    obj.test_function();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure as you code snippet doesn't specify if the lambda returns something or not - please follow ['minimal, reproducible example' principle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I think the problem might be that lambda returns no type (`void`) and your mock function `asyncfunc` returns non-void type (e.g. `bool`). In this case, you need to specify what shall be returned by the call to `asyncfunc` by using `Return` action:

```
struct MockClass {
    MOCK_METHOD3(asyncfunc, bool(bool, std::function<void(bool)>, int));
};

TEST(MockTest, CallLambda) {
    MockClass m{};

    auto param{false};

    EXPECT_CALL(m, asyncfunc(_, _, _)).WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeArgument<1>(param), Return(false)));

    ASSERT_FALSE(m.asyncfunc(
        true, [](bool) {}, 42)); // ASSERT_FALSE because `Return` action specified `false`
}
```

without `DoAll` and `Return` actions, gmock tries to use result of `InvokeArgument` as the return value of `asyncfunc` which it can't, because it cannot use `void` as `bool`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And the you are right! The asyncfunc() return type is bool, and the lambda function returns void. With DoAll and Return actions, I still get an error!!

Comment: Did it help? Or can you update the question so that it would be clear how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I modified the question. Sorry for the very abstract question! Please see if you can get any other hint

Comment: You only updated the code snippet, but it doesn't actually help with the whole question. Please provide more code: whole test if possible, mock class and how you create a mock object and maybe more of the error logs. It's hard to say what's going on

Comment: Ok. I ll follow the 'minimal, reproducible example' principle, Update the question...

Comment: Is `asyncfunc` part of `MockedObj` class API? In the code snippet I don't see it being called on an object - you can only mock methods of a class, not free functions. Can you share definition of the `MockedObj` class and how you have mocked it with `MOCK_METHODN`? Please see my example for reference. It's still hard to help you because I don't see the whole picture

Comment: I update the question with actual scenario. Hope you get the question now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220551/discussion-between-quarra-and-atul).